# How to make ASP.NET MVC appliaction for windows XP?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012

The windows XP installed on other machine uses .NET 3.5 which my clients will be using. I have an ASP.NET MVC 3 Intranet application built on .NET 4.0 framework on windows 8.1 and this PC will be a server for all the clients. Will this app run for them? On surfing I found that it wont and hence I should degrade my application to .NET 3.5 but there is no option of making ASP.NET MVC 3 when I choose the framework as .NET 3.5 Any suggestions how to do that? I'm using Visual Studio 2012

Comment: ASP.net MVC runs on ther server. The client machine make no difference as all it is to the end user is HTML, CSS and Javascript. Your only concern, client wise, is making sure that your CSS/Javascript/HTML works on your lowest browser which will be IE8 which will only give you buggy support for more modern CSS features.

Comment: So the frame work doesn't matter? and what about IIS? it needs to be installed on Client side?

Comment: IIS is only required on the sever, the S in IIS stands for Server after all. You only concern about the .net framework client side is if you use Silverlight components, which will probably be unlikely. You should probably do some more research on how Dynamicaly served websites work. For each website you visit, you don't need to install a web server, your browser is all you need as a consumer of a webpage, be it intranet or internet.

Comment: You only need to install .NET framework 4.0 on server where you are hosting application. Rest you browse it on any browser in any operating system.

Comment: okay thanks a lot. I'll google on that right away!

Answer (score 0):

you should try these links

[IIS 5.1 (Windows XP) and ASP.NET MVC Application](http://webactivedirectory.com/iis-microsoft/iis-5-1-windows-xp-and-asp-net-mvc-application-extension-mapping-bug/)

[Using ASP.NET MVC with Different Versions of IIS (VB)](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/deployment/using-asp-net-mvc-with-different-versions-of-iis-vb)

[Deploy ASP.NET MVC App on Windows XP (IIS 5.1)](http://itscommonsensestupid.blogspot.in/2008/11/deploy-aspnet-mvc-app-on-windows-xp-iis.html)

Hope it will solve your problem